# Exchange Powershell: Get-MailboxFolderPermission for all calendars

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have been working on a script to display permissions for all mailboxes at once, for a certain user at a time. Unfortunately, since the -Identity attribute in the Get-MailboxFolderPermission command doesn't accept wildcards, this is getting a bit complicated and messy.

I have started using an array to store all the mailboxes, so I can loop through it and run the command on each of them, but I've been unable to make this work because I haven't been able to reduce any of my outputs to just the email address. Here's my most recent iteration:

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox | Select Name -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses | Select AddressString
$MailboxList = @()
Foreach ($Box in $Mailboxes) {
    $BoxName = Out-String -InputObject $Box
    echo $BoxName | Out-File "box.txt"
    $BoxName = Select-String "box.txt" -Pattern "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b"
    echo $BoxName
    $MailboxList += $BoxName
    }
```

The problem with this code is that the $BoxName variable comes back with "box.txt:4:" text attached to it. Attempts to remove that text with -Replace have resulted in a full filepath being added.

I'm fairly new to Powershell, so even if this is just the entirely wrong approach, I would appreciate some pointers on how to do what I'm trying to do here.

Thanks

Comment: I realized that I missed some really important information as I was writing this. My end-goal for this script is that it will display access rights for the mailbox for each user. My current approach/logic is:

1. Get a list of mailboxes
2. Loop through the list of mailboxes, getting access rights for a specific user for each mailbox:\calendar in the list

Answer (score 1):

You could try to display permissions for all mailboxes using the below command:

```
 Get-Mailbox -Resultsize unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | Where { ($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") } | Select Identity,user,AccessRights
```

For more information, Please refer to this link:

[Get-MailboxPermission for multiple (all) users](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ae1331cc-1e36-417b-8044-b22933e7be80/getmailboxpermission-for-multiple-all-users?forum=exchange2010)